# Smallest number -- Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

This may sound really noobish, and I'm probably missing something really stupid.. But, I'm trying to calculate the differences between matrices, and the one with the smallest value (result) is the matching number.. But, for some reason my algorithm seems to be missing the smallest number and I can't figure out why..

Here is the code:

```
int min_val = 0;
double comp = 0;
const int ROW_BOUNDS(mat1Rows-mat2Rows+1);
const int COL_BOUNDS(mat1Cols-mat2Cols+1);

for(int i=0; (i < ROW_BOUNDS); i++) {
    for(int j=0; (j < COL_BOUNDS); j++) {
        m3.clear();
        for (int row(0); row < mat2Rows; row++){
            for (int col(0); col < mat2Cols; col++){
                //cout << matrix1[i*mat1Cols+row*mat1Cols+col+j] << ' ';
                m3.push_back( matrix1[i*mat1Cols+row*mat1Cols+col+j] );
                currentRow = i;
                currentCol = j;
            }
        }
        comp = compMatrix1(matrix2, m3);
        //printMatrix(m3, 2, 2);
        //cout << endl << " = " << comp << endl; 

        if(comp < min_val)
        {
            minRow = currentRow;
            minCol = currentCol;
            m4 = m3;
            min_val = comp;
            cout << min_val;
        }
    }
}    
//printMatrix(m4, 2, 2);
```

And here is the output:

```
0 0 
0 0 
    = 2
0 1 
0 1 
    = 4
1 0 
1 0 
    = 0
0 0 
1 1 
    = 2
0 1 
1 1 
    = 3
1 0 
1 0 
    = 0
1 1 
0 1 
    = 3
1 1 
1 0 
    = 1
1 0 
0 0 
    = 1
```

It prints:

```
  0 0 
  0 0
```

When the actual result should be:

```
1 0 
1 0
```

Could anyone offer any help please?

Comment: This is a bug-hunt in one particular piece of code and should be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few questions:

```
comp = compMatrix1(matrix2, m3);
```

what does compMatrix1 look like? What is matrix2?

Also can you explain what the following code does?

```
m3.push_back( matrix1[i*mat1Cols+row*mat1Cols+col+j] );
```

You may just be comparing matrices improperly or not filling m3 correctly. Also,

```
int min_val = 0;
```

Initializes the minimum value to be a lower than some values. What happens when the lowest value is actually 2? Then no matrix will have the min_val.

Answer (score 1):

Your `min_val` is zero, which means that your condition `if(comp < min_val)` only catches negative minims.

So, to fix this, change your

```
int min_val = 0;
```

to

```
int min_val = INT_MAX;
```

This ensures that the condition `(comp < min_val)` will be true for the first calculated matrix.

Comment: Heyy, Do you suggest me actually calculating the maximum value first, and then sorting depending on the lowest value?

Comment: @user1326876 No, you don't need to calculate any maximum value. `INT_MAX` is a constant defined in `limits.h`. If you have trouble with that, just use instead, `int min_val = 32767`

Comment: Or you can use `<limits>` and set `int min_val = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

Answer (score 0):

min_val should be initialized to be GREATER than the MAXIMUM possible value.

Comment: So shall I go through the values and then set the max_val to the min_val?

Comment: I said "possible": Your application may identify a value that comp can never be greater than, or you can go by the maximum value representable in an int.